# GORM: cannot INSERT into generated column

Tags: go, go-gorm

i have an issue with the generated columns value with GORM.

###### My struct

```golang
type Product struct {
    gorm.Model

    Name     string  `json:"name" gorm:"not null"`
    Quantity uint    `json:"quantity" gorm:"not null"`
    Price    float64 `json:"price" gorm:"not null"`
    Gain     float64 `json:"gain" gorm:"not null"`

    Total     float64 `json:"total" gorm:"->;type:GENERATED ALWAYS AS (quantity*price);"`     // generated total price
    TotalGain float64 `json:"total_gain" gorm:"->;type:GENERATED ALWAYS AS (quantity*gain);"` // generated total gain

    ProcessID uint // one-to-many
}
```

###### auto migration

```golang
    err = database.AutoMigrate(&models.Process{}, &models.Product{})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

This is the error

```
cannot INSERT into generated column "total"

[0.021ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO `products__temp`(`id`,`created_at`,`updated_at`,`deleted_at`,`name`,`quantity`,`price`,`gain`,`total`,`total_gain`,`process_id`) SELECT `id`,`created_at`,`updated_at`,`deleted_at`,`name`,`quantity`,`price`,`gain`,`total`,`total_gain`,`process_id` FROM `products`
```

It seems like GORM has created a temporary table "products__temp" a clone of "products" table.
So as we can know we cannot insert or edit the generated columns!

> Note: i'm working wih SQLite

Comment: if you want to write then you check [`field-level`](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#field_permission) permissions

Comment: No, this error is refer to the database it self, The rule of SQL said you cannot insert data into generated columns!
You can try it without GORM.

As i said the problem is when the GORM temporary table "products__temp" is created

Comment: Perhaps the tag `-:migration` should be added to the generated fields.
But I do not know if these fields will be created when creating the table.
https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#field_permission

Comment: i already tried the "-:migration" tag, it gives me the same problem!

Comment: @zakariachahboun please add the steps in your question how you are adding the records.

Comment: i didn't add any record, this error is refer to auto migration, it's not my fault!
 without the `Generated values` the migration woks just fine!

try to do this with your self using SQLite database

Comment: @zakariachahboun i tried running the above code didn't face any issue you can check the screenshot [here](https://imgur.com/a/1KYLiEi)

Comment: This code works for me without any problems: https://go.dev/play/p/HEMDWhWDnS3
Go version 1.19, GORM version 1.23.8.
Maybe the problem occurs when using other versions of Go and GORM?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Default-Values

**NOTE** You have to setup the default tag for fields having default or virtual/generated value in database, if you want to skip a default value definition when migrating, you could use `default:(-)`

Comment: The code work in the first time cuz there is no migration yet, But will not work in the second! That's why it will be always executed in `Go Playground` with no issues, But if you tried it in your local machine twice you will notice the issue.
 i also tried the `default:(-)` tag without any good result!

Comment: I think it would be nice if you publish your solution as an answer to your question. The rules approve this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is fixed by my pull request

https://github.com/go-gorm/sqlite/pull/109

the pull is accepted